# Integral of logarithm of Poisson kernel

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration

I would like to understand how should I compute using complex analysis the following integral,
$$I = \oint_{|z|=1}dz\,\ln\frac{1-|w|^2}{|w-z|^2},\quad |w|<1.$$
My attempt was following,
$$\ln\frac{1-|w|^2}{|w-z|^2}=\ln\left(1-|w|^2\right)-\ln\left|w-z\right|^2$$
and next notice that the second term is nothing more than also-called Poisson integral,
$$|w-z|^2=1-2r\cos(\theta-\phi)+r^2,\quad w=re^{i\phi},z=e^{i\theta}.$$
However, I assume that I am wrong because the first term is also gives zero. Could anyone please remind how to deal with following integral?

**Addendum:** Okey, it seems indeed zero. Let me check it in Wolfram Mathematica. For simplicity, let me use the following parametrization $w=re^{i\phi}$, $z=e^{i\theta}$, so
$$\ln\frac{1-|w|^2}{|w-z|^2}=\ln\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\phi-\theta)+r^2}.$$
The corresponding integral becomes
$$\oint_{|z|=1}dz\ln\frac{1-|w|^2}{|w-z|^2}=\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}d\theta\,e^{i\theta}i\ln\frac{1-r^2}{1-2r\cos(\phi-\theta)+r^2}\equiv J(r,\theta).$$
Let me evaluate the following cells,

```
J[r_, \[Phi]_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Exp[I*\[Theta]]*I*
   Log[(1 - r^2)/(1 - 2*r*Cos[\[Phi] - \[Theta]] + 
       r^2)], {\[Theta], -Pi, +Pi}];

Jvalues = Table[{r*Cos[\[Phi]], r*Sin[\[Phi]], Abs[J[r, \[Phi]]]}, {r, 0, 
   0.95, 0.05}, {\[Phi], -Pi, +Pi, 2*Pi/20}];

ListPlot3D[Flatten[Jvalues, 1]]
```

I explicitly plot `Abs` because I feel that the imaginary part exists. The result of last cell is:

[image]

Unfortunately, Mathematica works extremely slow for such integrals, so I cannot use `Integrate`. Nevertheless, let me check a specific case, $\phi=0$:

```
Integrate[
 Log[(1 - r^2)/(1 - 2*r*Cos[\[Phi] - \[Theta]] + r^2)], {\[Theta], -Pi, +Pi},
Assumptions -> {0 < r < 1}]
```

The result for this integration coincides with my integral up to multiplication by $i$. Wolfram Mathematica says:
$$-\frac{2i\pi^2}{3}+4\pi\ln r + i \ln r^2 + 2\pi\ln(1-r^2)+2i\text{Li}_{2}(r)+2i\text{Re}\,\text{Li}_{2}(1/r).$$

As was noticed in comments,
$$\ln(1-2r\cos(\phi-\theta)+r^2)=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{n}\cos\left[n(\phi-\theta)\right].$$
It seems that the integral over $\theta$ for this expression is not zero,
$$\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}d\theta\,e^{i\theta}\cos\left[n(\phi-\theta)\right]=\frac{2\sin(\pi n)e^{in\phi}}{n^2-1}.$$
Next, perform series summation,
$$-2i\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{r^n}{n}\frac{2\sin(\pi n)e^{in\phi}}{n^2-1}=2i\pi re^{i\phi}$$

So, it seems that integral is *not zero*.

Comment: $\ln|1-|w|^2|$ is just a constant, right? (assuming $|w|$) is a constant.  So, the integral of the first term would just be $2\pi \ln|1-|w|^2|$.

Comment: @Doug, yes, it the constant. Am I right that $\oint_{|z|=1}dz\,C$, where $C$ is the constant is zero? Is it wrong?

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After an easy simplification the given integral is equal to  $I=∮_{|z|=1}(-2)ln|z-w|dz$.

Now, let $w=δe^{i\phi}$, $δ<1$, be the constant and $z=e^{iθ}$ be the paremetrization of the unit circle.

Then $ I=∫_0^{2π}(-i)ln[1+δ^2-2δcos(θ-φ)]e^{iθ}dθ$.

Here, we may use (5) of https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/cms_upload/321916735744.pdf.bannered.pdf

We get $ I=2i∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{δ^n}{n}∫_0^{2π}cos(n(θ-φ))e^{iθ}dθ$,

And $I=i∑_{n=1}^{∞}\frac{δ^n}{n}∫_0^{2π}(e^{i(n+1)θ-ni\phi}+e^{i(1-n)θ+ni\phi})dθ$

But those integrals inside the summation are all zero excpet the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(1-n)θ+ni\phi}d\theta$ when $n=1$, which evaluates to $2\pi e^{i\phi}$.

Hence, $I=2\pi i\delta e^{i\phi}=2\pi i w$.

Note: For the naive "complex" solution, I thought about the integral of logarithm function around the unit disk. I saw this post: [What is the integral of log(z) over the unit circle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602614/what-is-the-integral-of-logz-over-the-unit-circle).

Now, I will try to make up a solution out of this mess. So far, I didn't like my solution at all.

The integral of this problem can be written in the form:
$$ I=-∮_{|z|=1}ln(z-w)dz-∮_{|z|=1}ln(\bar{z}-\bar{w})dz.$$
And further,
$$ I=-∮_{|z|=1}ln(z)dz-∮_{|z|=1}ln(\bar{z})dz-∮_{|z|=1}ln(1-\frac{w}{z})dz-∮_{|z|=1}ln(1-\frac{\bar{w}}{\bar{z}})dz.$$

Now, first two integrals cancel by our choice of fixed paremetrization. The third and the last integrals must be $2\pi i w$ and $0$ respectively.

Comment: Yes, I have seen this pdf. To be honest, I assume that "purely complex" computation is possible. What about the term $\ln(1-|w|^2)$? Does it indeed give zero contribution too or I am wrong?

Comment: $∮_{|z|=1}ln(1-|w|^2)dz=ln(1-|w|^2)∫_0^{2π}ie^{iθ}dθ=0$.

Comment: I have revised the question

Comment: It is not solved by residues. That is why I made a mistake.

Comment: Yes, it was my point. As I understand, the modulus is not holomorphic function and the Cauchy theorem can not be applied naively. Also, there are branch cuts due to log function.

Comment: However, for me it still not clear how this result correponds to the full integral. From numerics, it is easy to see that at $r\rightarrow\infty$ the result for integral is blowing up.

Comment: $r$ is fixed and less than 1.

Comment: I misprint, I mean $r\rightarrow 1$

Comment: I have no numerical experience for Poisson integrals.

Comment: I have checked my derivations and it seems right. Nevertheless, it is still open question why Mathematica give so strange result

Comment: I have checked my code and found the error